# HasOpenCV built-in functions to calculate circularity, compactness etc for contours/blobs?

Tags: opencv

Compactness can be defined for example as the perimeter squared, divided by 4*pi*area, so that a circle has a compactness of 1.

Before writing my own function, Is there a similar function in the OpenCV Library ?

Thanks.

Ps : SimpleBlobDetector does not help me as I want to calculate circularity for existing prior extracted contours.

Comment: Came across this question upon my search for the exact problem. First result was SimpleBlobDetector - can't help, and the second is this one. Have you succeeded in finding solution to this matter?